# String character removal

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write a function "Elimination" which has arguments S as string K1, K2 characters. The function needs to return a string which is obtained when you remove characters K1 and K2.

So if I forward to function ("Odgovornost","o",s") it returns "Odgvrnt".

I tried:

```
Function Eliminacija(S As String, K1 As String, K2 As String)
Dim I As Integer
For I = 1 To Len(S)

If Mid(S, I, 1) Like "K1" Or Mid(S, I, 1) Like "K2" Then
Mid(S, I, 1) = ""

End If
Next
Elimination = S
```

Comment: You cannot set `mid()` to `""`, and you cannot refer to a variable by providing its name as a string literal. Simply call `Replace()` twice on `S`. If you want to use `mid()` anyway, declare a buffer of original length of `S`, loop over `S` and only copy the current character into the buffer (with `mid() = `) if it does not equal `K1` or `K2`.

Comment: How did you mean to use Replace twice on S I didn't understand you very well sorry

Comment: `Replace(Replace(S, K1, ""), K2, "")`.

Comment: I gave a try, but doesn't work. :( I want just to eliminate char which is exact the same as K1 or K2. Looks pretty simple but cannot make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Remove Characters

### Replace Version

```
Function Eliminacija(S As String, K1 As String, K2 As String)

  S = Replace(S, K1, "")
  S = Replace(S, K2, "")

  Eliminacija = S

End Function
```

### Mid Version

```
Function Eliminacija(S As String, K1 As String, K2 As String)

  Dim i As Integer
  Dim str As String

  For i = 1 To Len(S)

    If Not Mid(S, i, 1) Like K1 And Not Mid(S, i, 1) Like K2 Then
      str = str & Mid(S, i, 1)
    End If

  Next

  Eliminacija = str

End Function
```